# Open inappbrowser with post data

Tags: android, cordova

I want to know how to open inappbrowser with post dataI've try like this:

```
var myWindow = window.open('', 'NewFile');
myWindow.doSomething = function () {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.action = "https://somesite.jsp";
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.target = 'NewFile';
    form.style.display = 'none';
    var submit = document.createElement('input');
    submit.type = 'submit';
    submit.id = 'submitProject';
    form.appendChild(submit);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
myWindow.addEventListener('load', myWindow.doSomething());
```

When I try it on the emulator, it works well, It will open a new window then the page is redirected to the form action url (still same window). 
But when I test it on real device, It will open new browser, but then after call form.submit(), this browser is closed and new page appeared with correct result. The big problem is I can't go back to my application when I click back button on my device, it stuck there and I must force close it to use my app again. Is there some other way how to open browser with post data and still can go back if we click back button?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I am also looking for solution to this, have you found any?